# Subtotal=Quantity*Unit_price Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the form  `addProductForm` , in this form I want to calculate `Subtotal=Quantity*Unit_price`.

```
this.addProductForm = this.fb.group({
      'product_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'Quantity': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'Unit_price': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'Subtotal': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
```

Html Code.

In html code, I want to display subtotale when I write unit_price and Quantity.

```
<form [formGroup]="addProductForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddProduct()" class="col s12" materialize style="text-align:center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <select formControlName="product_type_id" id="product_type_id" materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="producttype">
        <option value="" disabled selected>ProductTye*</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of producttype; let i=index;" [value]="item.product_type_id">{{item.product_type_name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number" class="validate">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="Unit_price" id="Unit_price" type="number" class="validate">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" type="number" class="validate">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="add_contrat_button_container" class="row">
    <button id="add_contrat_button" type="submit" class="button button1">
      SUBMIT
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a common change event for Quantity  and Unit_price input box. In the event, do the computation

```
this.addProductForm.Subtotal= this.addProductForm.Quantity* this.addProductForm.Unit_price
```